# can't select value of radio input in firefox, but works in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

So I use the following to capture the value of a radio button that is checked, and it works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox I just get undefined as the Activity value.

Any ideas on what it could be, or how I could fix it?

```
$("#registerResultsButton").click(function () {
    var Competition = $("body").attr("data-competitionId");
    var Activity = $('input:radio[name=group1]:checked').val();
    console.log(Competition + Activity);
});
```

The HTML looks like:

```
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1101" data-toggle="radio"> meetings taken (5 points)
        <label class="radio">
            <span class="icons">
                <span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span>
                <span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1111" data-toggle="radio"> closed restaurants (50 points)     
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <span class="icons">
                <span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span>
                <span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1121" data-toggle="radio"> upsell (100 points)
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your markup is exactly like that, it's invalid. Not that fixing it would solve your problem, but that's a good start.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PqRjS/ check your data attribute

Answer (score 0):

It should be `var Activity = $(':radio[name="group1"]:checked').val();`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with your radio button,the error is data attribute on your body check if it is defined because it says your attribute is undefined

Comment: The OP said the undefined was in the `Activity` var not in the `Competition` var.

Comment: do you see a body tag in his html? The html provided only seems to be a partial.

Comment: Its likely then that his use of the [:radio](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) selector and his version of jquery and version of firefox were to blame.

Comment: But then again you could be right. Only time will tell, assuming the OP responds again

Comment: Hi guys. Seems that the :radio selector and FF is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your activity is undefined try this:

```
var Activity = $('input[type="radio"][name="group1"]:checked').val();
```

This will check for inputs that have the type `radio` and the name `group1` and is checked then get the value.